# Get image with path from css

Tags: jquery

I have an element with inline-style that contains image-background property.  I am trying to extract image and its path from it with jQuery and then render the image by itself:

```
var img = $(this).css("background-image").replace(/url\(|\)/g, "");

$("#showImage").attr("src", img);
```

It's getting the source but the image isn't rendering because I'm getting double quotes on both sides.

```
<img src=""path/image.png"">
```

Need help with getting getting it working.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value path is probably wrapped in quotes within your CSS. The regular expression you are using is not going to filter out the quotes. Change it to this and it should work:

```
var img = $(this).css("background-image").replace(/url\("*|"*\)/g, "");
```